# How to attach files and store them in cells?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to attach files and store them in cells G2 and on.

However, every time I input it gets input in G2. If a user decides to enter more data the input data will iterate into a new row but the attachment stays in row G2 and takes the place of the previous one.

textbox2 in userform gets skipped every time I press enter. I want my users to navigate with keyboards but if I'm done in textbox1 and press enter it will throw me to textbox3 rather than textbox2.

```vb
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
    
    iRow = wrkSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    If Trim(RequesterBox.Value) = "" Then
        RequesterBox.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please complete the form"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = RequesterBox.Value
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = SquadronBox.Value
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = EmailBox.Value
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = PhoneBox.Value
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = LocationBox.Value
    wrkSht.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = DescriptionBox.Value
        
    MsgBox "Request has been added Succesfully. Thanks for you submition, someone will be contacting you shortly", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Thanks"
    '----------------------- Send Email-----------------------'
    
    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)
    
    emailItem.To = ""
    
    emailItem.Subject = "Facility Request"
    
    emailItem.Body = "A request for " & LocationBox.Value & " has been submited with the following description: " & Chr(10) & _
                      DescriptionBox.Value
    
    emailItem.Display
    
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailItemApplication = Nothing
    
    RequesterBox.Value = ""
    SquadronBox.Value = ""
    EmailBox.Value = ""
    PhoneBox.Value = ""
    LocationBox.Value = ""
    DescriptionBox.Value = ""
    RequesterBox.SetFocus
    
End Sub

Private Sub AttachButton_Click()

    Set wrkSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LinksList As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim LinkAttached As Long
    
    Set LinksList = Range("G2")
    Sheet1.Range("G2").Select

'declare last row to insert link to
    lastRowLink = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G"))
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow + 1, 11).Value = LinkAttached
  
    ChDrive "C:\"
    ChDir "C:\"
    Filt = "PNG Files(*.png),*.png ," & _
            "Jpeg Files(*.jpeg),*.jpg ," & _
            "PDF Files (*.pdf),*.pdf ," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*"
    FilterIndex = 1
    Title = "Select a File to Hyperlink"
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
         FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
         Title:=Title)
    If FileName <> False Then
       wrkSht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=LinksList, _
       Address:=FileName, _
       TextToDisplay:=FileName
    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbCritical, "Loading Error"
        Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hy i hope it will help you

Private Sub AttachButton2_Click()

```
Dim lastRow As Long, nextId As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newRecord As Range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    
With ws
    'getlcurrent last row
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    'get next Id
    nextId = Val(.Range("G" & lastRow).Value) + 1
    'set new record
    Set newRecord = .Range("G" & lastRow + 1)
    'insert data
    newRecord.Value = nextId


    'select file
    ChDrive "C:\"
    ChDir "C:\"
    Filt = "PNG Files(*.png),*.png ," & _
            "Jpeg Files(*.jpeg),*.jpg ," & _
            "PDF Files (*.pdf),*.pdf ," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*"
    FilterIndex = 1
    Title = "Select a File to Hyperlink"
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
         FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
         Title:=Title)
    If Filename <> False Then
       .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=newRecord, _
       Address:=Filename, _
       TextToDisplay:=Filename
    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbCritical, "Loading Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    


End With
```

End Sub